# Error on Python Json.load: Extra data line 10 column 2 (char 194)

Tags: python, json

I am new to python and am working on a project that require appending json data to a file data.txt after which i need to iterate over the data and filter email and password.

Here is my code

```
import json
from main import *
from jobs import *

def registration():
    ''' Register a user.'''
    print('''Welcome! \nRegister to get started \n''')
    data = {} # Container that wil hold user details before writing to a file

    fullname = input('Full name: ')
    email = input('Email address: ')
    phone_number = input('Phone number: ')
    password = input('Password: ')
    # append to users dictionary
    data['users'] = []
    data['users'].append({
        'Fullname': fullname,
        'Email': email,
        'Phonenumber': phone_number,
        'Password': password
    })
    # appending to a file
    with open('data.txt', 'a') as users_file:
        json.dump(data, users_file, indent=4)

    login()

def login():
    ''' Check if a user has registered and login the user after authentication''' 
    print('''Don't have an account yet?\n 1. Create account\n 2. Continue to login ''')
    user_response = input()
    if user_response == '1':
        return registration()

    with open('data.txt') as users_file:
        data = json.load(users_file)
        Email = input("email: ")
        Password =input("Password: ")
        for foo in data['users']:
            if foo["Email"] == Email and foo["Password"] == Password:
                x = foo["Email"] 
                y = foo["Password"]
                x == y  is True
                #Creates a login session for a staff and saves it to session.txt
                print (f"Welcome! logged in as {Email}")
                keyword_post = input('1. Search job by keyword\n 2. Register a job')
                if keyword_post == '1':
                    return keywords()
                return job_list()
            else:
                print('Invalid email or password.')
                return login()
```

I am getting **raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 10 column 2 (char 194)** error message whenever more than one user registered. Please i need help on how to resolve this.

Comment: your txt file most likely isnt a valid json format. can you show/post the txt in that file that gives you that error?

Comment: Tried your code, as I thought, it's not a valid json. You need a comma in between entries, also, It's not really efficient. You don't want a repeat of your "users" key, but rather all users under nieth that key

Comment: This is the txt file

Comment: {"users": [
        {
            "Fullname": "Emma",
            "Email": "emma@gmail.com",
            "Phonenumber": "23543748483",
            "Password": "password"
        }
    ]
}{
    "users": [
        {
            "Fullname": "Admin",
            "Email": "admin@gmail.com",
            "Phonenumber": "6483627388",
            "Password": "admin"
        }
    ]
}

Comment: Please how can i change the code to give me Json format of the txt file?

Answer (score 1):

You need a comma between each entry. It also doesnt make sense to have the key "users" repeated. That should be your key, then within that key, your list of user parameters/info

Couple of other things:

I'm not sure what this is doing for you:

```
           x = foo["Email"] 
           y = foo["Password"]
           x == y  is True
```

I took it out as x == y will always return False, so I'm not sure why store as x and y variables, and `x == y  is True` just doesn't make sense.

Another thing to consider is emails (unlike passwords) are not case sensitive, so you need to anticipate that. so someone should not be able to register `USER@email.com` and `user@email.com`...it's the same email address. So store emails as either all upper or lower case.

I made a few minor changes as well, doesn't change the logic, but added a few prints (If wrong password, if email already exists, etc.) You can also continue to add some checks in there too using `regex`. So things like, email address needs to be in the form of `xxxx@xxxxxxx.com` So if it doesn't have the `@` or `.com`, `.edu`, dot whatever, it'll not accept the email address. Or phone number needs to follow a certain pattern. But that you can do later, if needed.

You also don't NEED to `'user'` key in there (unless you'll be adding some other key into the json later??) I'm not sure as I don't know what your end is to look like or be used for. It doesn't hurt to have it there though, so not a big deal, but it just adds another level that may or may not be needed.

Try this:

```
import json
import os
from main import *
from jobs import *

def registration():
    #### Register a user ####
    print('Welcome!\nRegister to get started\n')
    inputdata = {} # Container that will hold user details before writing to a file

    fullname = input('Full name: ')
    email = input('Email address: ').lower()
    phone_number = input('Phone number: ')
    password = input('Password: ')
    # append to users dictionary
    inputdata['users'] = {}
    inputdata['users'][email] = {}
    inputdata['users'][email].update({
        'Fullname': fullname,
        'Phonenumber': phone_number,
        'Password': password
    })
    # appending to a file
    if os.path.isfile('data.txt'):
        with open('data.txt', 'r') as users_file:
            dataFile = json.load(users_file)
        # Check if email already exists
        if email in dataFile['users'].keys():
            print ('Can not register this email. Email already in use.')
            return login()

        dataFile['users'].update(inputdata['users'])
        with open('data.txt', 'w') as users_file:
            json.dump(dataFile, users_file, indent=4)

    else:
        with open('data.txt', 'w') as users_file:
            json.dump(inputdata, users_file, indent=4)
    login()

def login():
    ''' Check if a user has registered and login the user after authentication''' 
    print('''Don't have an account yet?\n 1. Create account\n 2. Continue to login ''')
    user_response = input()
    if user_response == '1':
        return registration()

    with open('data.txt') as users_file:
        data = json.load(users_file)
        Email = input("Email: ").lower()
        Password =input("Password: ")

        userEmailList = list(data['users'].keys())
        if Email not in userEmailList:
            print ('Email is not registered.')
            return login()
        fooPassword = data['users'][Email]['Password']
        if fooPassword == Password:
            x = Email
            y = fooPassword
            x == y  is True   
            #Creates a login session for a staff and saves it to session.txt
            print (f"Welcome! logged in as {Email}")
            keyword_post = input('1. Search job by keyword\n2. Register a job')
            if keyword_post == '1':
                return keywords()
            return job_list()
        else:
            print('Invalid password.')
            return login()
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked. I am upvoting your answer. Thank you.

Comment: The login function only iterate over first dictionary in the list. Any clue on how to modify it?

Comment: You’ll have to have it iterate through each item.

Comment: What I would do is iterate through each item to first find a match on email. Once you find a match on email, check for match on password. I’m done for today? But o can update that for you early tomorrow

Comment: Yes. Since the key is users, why isn't the function iterating over each item?

Comment: Because it’s a list. You have iterate through the list of users. Better yet, I think having the key as the email address is better. You can search quicker, and then it also won’t allow duplicate emails to be used.

Comment: having the key as the email address is good. I tried it before but the structure is not ok. I wish you can edit the code so from your end. Thanks

Comment: Like I said adjust it tomorrow. So you’ll have all users entered under their email address as the key. And under the email will be their info.

Comment: Ok.Thank you.Tomorrow then.

Comment: @Chuks, give it try now

Comment: Thank you so much. I learnt something in your code. Thank you. Wish i can follow u on twitter or any other channel. Much to learn from you.